# DirectX 11 -- Hello Triangle Not Rendering -- Cause: Multithread C++ Run-Time Library

Tags: c++, multithreading, directx

The Tutorial works when Linked to **Single-Threaded Run-Time Library**:

http://www.rastertek.com/dx11s2tut04.html

Visual Studio 2017 -- Single-Threaded Run-Time Library is not an option.

Property Manager -> Common Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime

```
Multi-Threaded (/MT)
Multi-Threaded Debug (/MTd)
Multi-Threaded DLL (/MD)
Multi-Threaded DLL Debug (/MDd)
```

Solution 1) How to link with Single-Threaded Run-Time Library with Visual Studio 2017 or 2019.

Solution 2) A Hello Triangle tutorial that has Deferred Context, not Immediate Context.

Comment: You should be able to link multithreaded runtime without any problems.

Comment: Linking is not an issue. The screen stays gray and does not draw the triangle because the multi-threaded run-time has data race issue.

Comment: *"because the multi-threaded run-time has data race issue"* - I doubt it. Most likely you are doing something wrong. Anyway, if you have an issue then you should describe it and provide [mcve].

Comment: It works when linked with Single-Threaded Run-Time.

Comment: Before accessing COM infrastructure a thread needs to be initialized for COM. The tutorial doesn't appear to be calling `CoInitializeEx` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CameraClass
{
public:
    CameraClass();
    CameraClass(const CameraClass&);
    ~CameraClass();

    void SetPosition(float, float, float);
    void SetRotation(float, float, float);

    XMFLOAT3 GetPosition();
    XMFLOAT3 GetRotation();

    void Render();
    void GetViewMatrix(XMMATRIX&);

private:
//  I Used
    XMVECTOR position;
    XMVECTOR rotation;
//  instead of 
//  float m_positionX, m_positionY, m_positionZ;
//  float m_rotationX, m_rotationY, m_rotationZ;

    XMMATRIX m_viewMatrix;
};
```

Thus, Non-Virtual Methods have a function pointer cost per instance; or at least on the first instance.